# Entity Framework Two foreign key in one table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have two Entities:

```
public class Person {
    [Key]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public virtual Phone homePhone {get;set;} 
    public virtual Phone cellPhone {get;set;}
}

public class Phone {
    [Key]
    public int PhoneNumber {get;set;}

    public virtual Person {get;set;} 
}
```

One person can have zero or one homePhone and zero or one cellPhone. (I am thinking this as one to one or zero relation).

How to model this with Entity Framework using CodeFirst API. I can model a one to zero/one relationship between Person and Phone by setting Person as both primarykey and foreignkey of Phone but than how can both homePhone and cellPhone have same person entity? In the other way round can I say that there is an one to zero/one relation between Phone and Person where each Person has two Phone foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

You should think of something like this:

```
public class Person {
    [Key]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    Public PersonPhone HomePhone{get; set;}

    Public PersonPhone CellPhone{get; set;}        
}   

public class Phone {
    [Key]
    public int PhoneNumber {get;set;}
}

public class PersonPhone {
    [Key]
    public virtual Phone Phone {get;set;}

    [Key]
    public PhoneType PhoneType {get;set;}
}

public enum PhoneType {
    HomePhone,
    CellPhone 
}
```

Comment: but that will not restrict a person to have more than two phones. A person can have atmost one homephone and one cell phone

Comment: it is throwing an exception that there is no key defined for PersonPhone. What should be the key

Answer (score 0):

You can add another table that is used to create phone types and then each phone must have at least one phone type:

```
public class Person
{
    [key]
    public string name {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones {get;set;}
}

public class Phone
{
    [key]
    public int PhoneNumber {get;set;}

    public int PhoneTypeId {get;set;}
    public virtual PhoneType PhoneType {get;set;}
}

public class PhoneType
{
    [key]
    public int PhoneTypeId {get;set;}
    public string PhoneTypeDescription {get;set}
}
```